Zabbix not collecting data after upgrade
I was using Zabbix 5.0 in one server. I have installed Zabbix 6.0 in another server and pointing to older Zabbix database. Zabbix did the database migration by itself.
After migration I am able to login to new Zabbix all hosts are migrated properly , I can see all the actions, triggers everything migrated properly. But its not collecting new data.
For testing I exported one host , deleted that host and imported back then its working fine. But if I do like this for all host's I will be missing history of datas.
Any solution for this..?
